# htaccess rewrite URL with Google tracking code

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

First of all, sorry for my english... I hope you're going to understand my problem :)

My company has made an emailing campaign which included a link to our website. This URL has a Google tracking code to follow the campaign.

Unfortunately, the URL is wrong :

```
http://www.mysite.fr/category/mypage.html/?utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium&utm_campaign=campaign
```

but there's a slash between "mypage.html" and the tracking code which points to an inexistant page.

I tried these rules to redirect the url without sending a new email to everyone but they don't work :

```
RewriteRule ^/category/mypage\.html/\?utm_source\=source\&utm_medium\=medium\&utm_capaign\=campaign$ http://www.mysite.fr/category/mypage.html?utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium&utm_campaign=campaign [R=301,L]
```

Or :

```
RedirectPermanent /category/mypage.html/ http://www.mysite.fr/category/mypage.html?utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium&utm_campaign=campaign
```

I don't know how to write the rule. Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are wrong with your `RewriteRule`. If you're putting this in an .htaccess file, you need to remove the leading slash (the prefix) in your regular expression because apache removes it from the URI before putting it through rules in .htaccess files. Second, you can't match against the query string (the stuff starting from the **?**) in the regular expression in a `RewriteRule`.

Not sure why your `RedirectPermanent` isn't working. That looks fine other than the fact that the query strings automatically get appended if you leave them out. I think that's what you want, so remove the query string in the target:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/mypage.html/$ http://www.mysite.fr/category/mypage.html
```

Comment: Merci pour Votre response J'ai essayé votre solution, mais il dirige une autre erreur: 310(net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT)